# How to get index from json file in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have a json file where I can display all the contents from it in a view.

```
struct Test: View{
    let quizzs = Bundle.main.decode([Quizz].self, from: "capitals.json")

    var body: some View{
        ScrollView {
            VStack{
                ForEach(quizzs!, id: \.self){ item in
                    Text(item.country)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I want to be able to display a country of index[n]

I tried doing this:

```
@State var index = 0

Text(item.country[index])
```

But I get this error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Range<String.Index>'
```

How can I make it possible so that I can get a country at index n?

Comment: `item.country` is obviously a single object, according to the error message it's a string. `item.country[0]` – if `Int` subscription worked – points to the first character of the string. This is most likely not what you want. There is not enough information in the question to know what you do want.

Comment: I don't know what you mean, can you give an example about JSON data or show the `Quizz` struct

Answer (score 0):

It seems each item has the same country of the array structure. So you can use the index to get the corresponding country.
Try the following ways of writing to meet your needs.

```
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(Array(quizzs.enumerated()), id: \.self) { index, item in
                     Text("\(item.country[index])")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is considered unsafe for SwiftUI. You should watch demystify SwiftUI